# Refactor a method to using stream API

Tags: java, list, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

I am currently told to count all .sql files which are hangin' out on some servers. Manually solving this very *basic* task is not an option, instead, I wrote some code that makes use of a `SimpleFileVisitor<Path>` and stores all the sql files found along with its parent path in a `Map<Path, List<Path>>`.

Now I want to receive the total amount of sql files found independent from their locations. I got it working with an enhanced `for` loop (almost the classic way):

```
public int getTotalAmountOfSqlFiles(Map<Path, List<Path>> sqlFilesInDirectories) {
    int totalAmount = 0;
        
    for (Path directory : sqlFilesInDirectories.keySet()) {
        List<Path> sqlFiles = sqlFilesInDirectories.get(directory);
        totalAmount += sqlFiles.size();
    }
        
    return totalAmount;
}
```

The question is now, **how can I do the same using the stream API?**

I wasn't able to get compilable code to work which isn't obviously doing the wrong thing.
The following line looks like *a good idea* to me, but not to the compiler, unfortunately.

```
totalAmount = sqlFilesInDirectories.entrySet().stream().map(List::size).sum();
```

The compiler says

> Cannot infer type argument(s) for `<R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R>`

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong (and maybe provide some educated stream-API using solution)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure why people are involving `keySet` here when the required sum is only of List size contained in values. Just sum the size of all values.

```
return sqlFilesInDirectories.values().stream().mapToInt(List::size).sum();
```

And even the for loop version should be simply this,

```
for (List<Path> list : sqlFilesInDirectories.values()) {
    totalAmount += list.size();
}
```

As iterating over keyset and then getting value from map isn't really required and will not be better performance wise.

Answer (score 4):

It's because in stream you're taking whole entries instead of values. This should do it:

```
totalAmount = sqlFilesInDirectories.values().stream().map(List::size).sum();
```

Answer (score 3):

Other answers provide the shortest way to sum all entries, but if you need the amount of scripts per `Path` you can use the following:

```
Map<Path, Integer> amountOfFilesForPath =
        files.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
        Collectors.summingInt(value -> value.getValue().size())));
```

And you can also get the total value:

```
int sum = amountOfFilesForPath.values().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
int totalAmount = sqlFilesInDirectories.keySet().stream().map(sqlFilesInDirectories::get).mapToInt(List::size).sum();
```